# React Native 2 column flatlist specific styles: How can I make the first column be a bit lower than the 2nd column?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

[Image below take a look please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayb6K.png)

As you can see in the image below I have to make the first column a bit lower but 2nd line shouldn't be at the same level as it is currently. I'm using vertical flatlist with numcolumns=2

Tried to do it with marginTop for the first element but other items are on the same level?
How can I accomplish that ?

Answer (score 3):

In `FlatList` `renderItem` try this,

```
    const renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
       return (
               <View style={{ marginTop: index % 2 ? 0 : 10 }}>
               </View>
              );
    }
```

Comment: this should work @Shivam :)